# Page size only 99.6264% of the true requested size

Tags: geometry

I recently found that if you use the `\geometry` package to change the page size, then the actual page size is only 99.6264% of the requested page size. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[papersize={1000pt,1000pt}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
    Test ...
\end{document}
```

Now checking the output using `pdfinfo` shows:

```
...
Page size:      996.264 x 996.264 pts
...
```

It should have been 1000pt by 1000pt. I tried many combinations of the options and none worked. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance,

GI

Comment: Welcome into the group of the users of TeX.SE.

Comment: Use `\geometry{papersize={1000bp,1000bp}}`. TeX points and pdf points differ.

Comment: To elaborate on @UlrikeFischer's solution: a TeX `pt` is 1/72.27 of an inch, based on the best data that Knuth was able to find about printing / typesetting conventions at the time (the exact value of a point varied, but this was closest). Later, when Adobe developed PostScript (and later PDF), they standardized on 1/72 of an inch as the value of a point, and this is what most of the world now uses -- in TeX that value is available as `bp`, for "big point". (I think there must be a question on this site already that goes into this...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adobe's definition of typographic "point size", which has become the industry standard over the years, differs from TeX's definition. TeX sets

```
72.27pt=1inch
```

whereas Adobe (and much of the rest of the publishing industry) sets

```
72pt=1inch
```

The ratio of the two sizes is `72/72.27 = 0.996264 = 99.6262%`, which is exactly the number you've come up with as well.

If you wish to use Adobe's definition of "point size" in a TeX or LaTeX document, you need to use -- as @UlrikeFischer has already pointed out in a comment -- the unit `bp`, short for "big point". E.g.,

```
\geometry{papersize={1000bp,1000bp}}
```